# Restcomm - Solving SMSC GW 7.2 configuration failures

Tags: jboss, sms-gateway, smpp, restcomm, ss7

We configured the latest version (7.2) SMSC-GW to work on on our server with the environment (cassandra and such). However, after setting up everything. Some failures are appearing (which did not appear in previous versions).

Firstly, when connecting the simulators and the gateway using the default settings (JSS7 <-> SMSCGW <-> SMPP)

1. JSS7 is connected and sending, but no response is received.
2. SMPP is connected to SMSC-GW and the EMSE is bound. SMPP tries to send to SS7 but receives a response PDU packet failure from the SMSC-GW

I tried configuring DB routing rules, but that did not work.

Also, the log in the SMSC-GW server is frequently displaying the following message:

```
16:00:28,504 INFO  [SchedulerResourceAdaptor] (pool-56-thread-1) Not all SBB are running now: ServicesDownList=[smscTxSmppServerServiceState, smscRxSmppServerServiceState, smscTxSipServerServiceState, smscRxSipServerServiceState, smscTxHttpServerServiceState, moServiceState, homeRoutingServiceState, mtServiceState, alertServiceState, chargingServiceState, ]
```

And the JSS7 management console GUI is displaying this (which looks wrong):

[image]

So are these the source of the SMSC-GW failures?

UPDATE: I found this error in the server.log

```
2017-02-02 10:57:42,005 WARN  [org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.SleeContainerDeployerImpl] (SLEE-InternalDeployer-thread-1) SLEE DUs not deployed, due to missing dependencies: file:/home/coreteam/kitchensink/restcomm-smsc-7.2.109/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/simulator/deploy/smsc-services-du-7.2.109.jar/
```

Followed by:

```
EventTypeID[name=org.mobicents.smsc.slee.services.smpp.server.events.SS7_SEND_MT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
ResourceAdaptorTypeID[name=PersistenceResourceAdaptorType,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
ResourceAdaptorTypeID[name=SchedulerResourceAdaptorType,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
SipRA
EventTypeID[name=org.mobicents.smsc.slee.services.smpp.server.events.SS7_SEND_RSDS,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
SchedulerResourceAdaptor^M
PersistenceResourceAdaptor^M
EventTypeID[name=org.mobicents.smsc.slee.services.smpp.server.events.SMPP_SM,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
EventTypeID[name=org.mobicents.smsc.slee.services.smpp.server.events.SS7_SM,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
EventTypeID[name=org.mobicents.smsc.slee.services.smpp.server.events.SIP_SM,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
2017-02-02 14:41:17,450 WARN  [org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.DeploymentManager] (main) Unable to INSTALL smsc-services-du-7.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar right now. Waiting for dependencies to be resolved.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it quite a while ago, but thought I would share. I just simply installed the SipRA missing dependency by adding the following in the *deploy-config.xml* file:

```
<ra-entity
resource-adaptor-id="ResourceAdaptorID[name=JainSipResourceAdaptor,vendor=net.java.slee.sip,version=1.2]"
entity-name="SipRA">
<properties>
    <property name="javax.sip.PORT" type="java.lang.Integer" value="5060" />
</properties>
<ra-link name="SipRA" />
```

In the $JBOSS_HOME/server/profile_name/deploy/restcomm-slee directory.

I set the port to some other value since that number was already taken by some other service.

The `smsc-services-du-7.2.109.jar` then installed automatically the next time I ran the SMSC-GW.